# Multi-threaded matrix multiplication in the main thread doesn't wait until the other threads finish their work?

Tags: c, multithreading

In this program the main thread doesn't wait for child threads but when I replace the position of pthread_join and put it in for-loop after pthread_create, the main thread will wait for child threads.

I think if I do that I remove the advantage of multi-threads program because the main thread will wait after creating each thread until it finish its work so the program doesn't work in parallel.

Could anyone help me to find the solution to this problem thanks in advance?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>


int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int b[3][2]={{8,9},{7,2},{5,6}};
int c[3][2];
int a_rows=3,a_cols=3,b_rows=3,b_cols=2;


struct dimensions
{
  int row;
  int col;
};

 //method computes C[i][j] in the output C matrix**/
void *matrix_mulCell(void * arg)
{
   struct dimensions *d=arg;
   int sum=0;
   int k;
for(k=0; k<b_rows; ++k)
{
    sum+=(a[d->row][k]*b[k][d->col]);
}
c[d->row][d->col]=sum;
 /**Exit the thread*/
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main()
{
     int i,j;
     pthread_t threads2[a_rows][b_cols];
     struct dimensions *d=(struct dimensions *) malloc(sizeof(struct dimensions));
    for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
        {
            d->row=i;
            d->col=j;
            /**create thread to compute the value of element c[i][j]**/
            if( pthread_create(&threads2[i][j], NULL, matrix_mulCell, d))
            {
                printf("Can not create a thread\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }


 for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
  {
    for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
    {
                      /**Make sure the parent waits for all thread to complete**/
            pthread_join(threads2[i][j],NULL);
    }
}

/**print the result **/
for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
{
    for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and indent the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this my answer after add edit of @milevyo (make new struct for each thread) and make main threads wait for other threads  at the end of the program before printing matrix not after create the child thread

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int b[3][2]={{8,9},{7,2},{5,6}};
int c[3][2];

int a_rows=3,a_cols=3,b_rows=3,b_cols=2;
struct dimensions
{
  int row;
  int col;
};

//method computes C[i][j] in the output C matrix**/
void *matrix_mulCell(void * arg)
{
 struct dimensions *d=arg;
 int sum=0;
 int k;
for(k=0; k<b_rows; ++k)
{
    sum+=(a[d->row][k]*b[k][d->col]);
}
c[d->row][d->col]=sum;
/**Exit the thread*/
free(d);// thread is responsible of freeing it
pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main(void)
{
     int i,j;
     pthread_t threads2[a_rows][b_cols];
     memset(c,0,sizeof(c));

   struct dimensions *d;
   for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
   {
       for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
       {
           // allocate for each thread it own struct
          // thread it self will free it
        d=malloc(sizeof(struct dimensions));
        d->row=i;
        d->col=j;
        /**create thread to compute the value of element c[i][j]**/
        if( pthread_create(&threads2[i][j], NULL, matrix_mulCell, d))
        {
            printf("Can not create a thread\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
  for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
        {
            /**make main thread wait for child threads**/
     pthread_join(threads2[i][j],NULL);
    }
    }
/**print the result **/
for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
{
    for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int b[3][2]={{8,9},{7,2},{5,6}};
int c[3][2];

int a_rows=3,a_cols=3,b_rows=3,b_cols=2;
struct dimensions
{
  int row;
  int col;
};

 //method computes C[i][j] in the output C matrix**/
void *matrix_mulCell(void * arg)
{
    struct dimensions *d=arg;
    int sum=0;
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<b_rows; ++k)
    {
        sum+=(a[d->row][k]*b[k][d->col]);
    }
    c[d->row][d->col]=sum;
    /**Exit the thread*/
    free(d);// thread is responsible of freeing it
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main(void)
{
     int i,j;
     pthread_t threads2[a_rows][b_cols];
    memset(c,0,sizeof(c));

    struct dimensions *d;
    for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
        {
            // allocate for each thread it own struct
            // thread it self will free it
            d=malloc(sizeof(struct dimensions));
            d->row=i;
            d->col=j;
            /**create thread to compute the value of element c[i][j]**/
            if( pthread_create(&threads2[i][j], NULL, matrix_mulCell, d))
            {
                printf("Can not create a thread\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            pthread_join(threads2[i][j],NULL);
        }
    }
    /**print the result **/
    for(i=0; i<a_rows; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<b_cols; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think in this case the main thread wait after creating a thread until this thread finish its work and then the program doesn't work in parallel

Comment: indeed it does wait, the problem was, you where passing the same struct to all thread, and that struct was updated on each creation of the thread, thus, on thread calculation it get wrong row & col.